# Edit insert row functionality in worksheets VBA

Tags: vba, insert, worksheet

In some worksheets, but not the workbook, I want to modify the insert row command to copy the formatting and functionalities from the preceding row into the new row.

I have a macro for this but cannot figure out how to insert it into/run it from a worksheet change event when the user selects insert row, or how to edit Excel's Insert Row command to do this.

The macro is:

```
Sub InsertCopyRow()
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
End Sub
```

Comment: not sure there is an event you can use for that - i guess you could make a button for inserting rows and use the onclick() event handler

Comment: Thanks, James - that seems to be the case, so a button is the route I'll take! Charles